# ADF with Power Query: extra line in CSV output?

Tags: powerquery, azure-data-factory

I'm using a Power Query block in an ADF pipeline to aggregate and transform some data, and then put in a sink as a delimited (CSV) file (in ADL GEN2).
The issue I'm having is that the outputted CSV file contains an extra line:

```
COL1, COL2
v1, 500
v2, 800
v3, 900
,1200
```

The "extra line" is not present in the power query editor when I view it in ADF Studio. Nor should it be there as there are no empty values in COL1 (on which I'm aggregating).

The query I'm using:

```
let Source = #"StagingHerverkoopAanbod",
  #"Grouped rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"kantoor1_referentie"}, {{"Aantal Panden", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}}),
  #"Sorted rows" = Table.Sort(#"Grouped rows", {{"kantoor1_referentie", Order.Ascending}}),
  #"Added custom" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Table.AddColumn(#"Sorted rows", "Timestamp", each DateTime.LocalNow()), {{"Timestamp", type datetime}}) in #"Added custom"
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your CSV have fields in double quotes otherwise how will it know which comma is a delimiter and which is actual data?

Could also be related to Csv.Document Quote Style

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/csv-document

> QuoteStyle: Specifies how quoted line breaks are handled.
> QuoteStyle.None (default): All line breaks are treated as the end of
> the current row, even when they occur inside a quoted value.
> QuoteStyle.Csv: Quoted line breaks are treated as part of the data,
> not as the end of the current row.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My data is using double quotes and I triple checked the source files. The data is fairly simple (think product / revenue dataset) with no comma's in the data.

Comment: Can you post your query? Have you changed the quote style in the CSV.Document function?

Comment: Updated my question with the query. Note that when I'm viewing the query in the editor, the "added line" isn't present in the query output.

Comment: To clarify: in the Power Query editor I'm seeing 56 lines, in the CSV file saved to the ADL container, I see 57 lines.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the dataset but this looks like you have blanks in kantoor1_referentie. If it is working in the editor though, it could be a genuine bug that you need to report to MS.

Comment: I checked the source dataset manually (only has 1300 rows) and I'm sure it doesn't contain any blanks.